# Playwright: Using ReqExp inside of the URL while trying to check PUT request via page.waitForResponse()

Tags: automated-testing, mocha, chai, playwright

Currently in one of my test I am trying to check PUT request status. In one of the user scenarios when a user clicks `Confirm` button a PUT request is sent and if all good status code 200 is present in the Network tab. As far as I am aware in Playwright there is an option to check such things. According to https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response it is possible to achieve that.

Now the issue that I am facing is that each time when a PUT request is sent to the destination endpoint, a random case number is present in the request. To avoid time and work I thought that I could use a `ReqExp such as \d+` for that. However during the execution of the test, I can see by using Playwright API logs that the `page.waitForResponse()` fails each time. I know that the endpoint works correctly so there is no issue with it. I assume that my implementation of using `ReqExp` is causing all the fuzz.

Below I am placing my example method with the `ReqExp`. The place in the URL where the number is generated has been replaced with the following expression `\d+`. I want to make it a reusable method so I am not interested in the actual number, I know it will be there. I am more interested in the status code. If someone is more experience with those, please share some useful guidance. Thanks you all!

```
async confirmDealAsXYZ() {
    await this.page.waitForSelector(
      'span:has-text("Please confirm you would like to mark this deal as containing XYZ")'
    );
    await this.page.waitForSelector('div[class="ant-modal-footer"]');
    // await this.page.click('div[role="dialog"] button:has-text("Confirm")');

    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-regex-literals
    const re = new RegExp(
      `https://myapplication-dev.net/some_ship_financing/some_new_finance/api/v1/some_cases/d+/assessment/xyz/`
    );

    await Promise.all([
      // Waits for the next response with the specified url
      this.page.waitForResponse(response => response.url() === re && response.status() === 200),
      // Triggers the response
      this.page.click('div[role="dialog"] button:has-text("Confirm")'),
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes as far as I can see:

**1/** strictly comparing a string object with a different object (`re`) will always return `false`:

You need to use some method like [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), for example:

```javascript
let re = new RegExp('\\d+');
re.test('1234'); // this returns true
```

**2/** if you pass a string to the `RegExp` constructor, you need to escape characted classes with `\\`:

```javascript
let re = new RegExp('\\d+');
re.test('1234'); // this returns true
```

doing only:

```javascript
let re = new RegExp('\d+');
re.test('1234'); // this returns false
```

or:

```javascript
let re = new RegExp('d+');
re.test('1234'); // this returns false
```

doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: thanks for useful answers, share more light on my work. Now I know where was wrong. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple alternative using 'includes'

Responses also can be verified simply using 'includes':

(by including the desired unique substring from the url)

```
page.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url().includes('/assessment/xyz/') && resp.status() === 200)
```

Docs:
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response